# Upload media with Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Currently we are integrating Instragram with our platform and need a feature to automatically upload media (like youtube and facebook). We have gone thorugh the developer portal and found no documentation about media upload.
I have googled for a while and no positive results. The below url(instagram offical API) lists the endpoint. It only has GET media related APIs
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

- GET/media/media-id
- GET/media/shortcode/shortcode
- GET/media/search

**Question:**

Has anyone been in similar situation? is there anywork around?

Comment: currently there is no API to upload media, you have to use the INstagram app

Comment: i just found a good documentaion about media upload in instagram check the link bellow.

Comment: instagran have no direct option to upload media,
but using facebook api https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/ allow to share in instagram but facebook revise their policy for developer api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending considerable amount of time, Concluded that - as of today it is not possible legally. The workarounds seems to reverse engineer the actual media post by Instagram. And strict against the privacy policy and Instagram can take legal action. Hence, as of today

**Media cannot be uploaded with Instagram API**

However, you can

- Add/Remove comments on a media
- Set/Remove Like on a media

with Instagram API.

Hope it will save someone time, unless Instagram revisits its APIs on media.