# I need to have all Instagram API endpoints

Tags: php, api, curl, instagram

I want to use Instagram API. I'm able to use API using code and token. In my account I just have 2 endpoints. I want to know why ? Why there is not media endpoints for example ?

[image: My endpoints]

> [Upload media with Instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204248/upload-media-with-instagram-api)

Thanks to this post I saw that It was not possible to add media.
Today is this still the case ?

I want to allow to users of my website to share media like images, so I don't know why there is no media

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "why" questions should go to the developers of the API.

Comment: These endpoints is no longer available, Instagram is closing that API in 2020. Please check Instagram Graph API instead.

Comment: Its not that he does not want to help you, its because such questions are not for StackOverflow. This board is for a specific problem within your code, which you did not even post. As he said, thats a question for the devs of said API.

Comment: i disagree with you @Manuel Mannhardt because when we create a new post we have to choose the type of problem like code, hardware recommendation etc

Comment: Please see: [Why we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions). Only the developer of the API can answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These endpoints is no longer available, Instagram is closing that API in 2020. Please check Instagram Graph API instead.

Go to >> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

Comment: I'm confused - is this supposed to be an answer, or an addition to your question? If it's the first case, please [edit] to be more clear about that; in the latter case, you should just edit this into the question rather than adding more information in the answer section.